# JavaFX date picker keep calendar open and select a series of days

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Hello i am new to JavaFX and would like to use a date picker,in swing i used a jdate picker that allowed me to use a combo box picker(similar to the javaFX one) however also let me have an open calendar, the user could select one day or several(by shift clicking)
How do i get this on javaFX?

Comment: JavaFX 8+ has the [`DatePicker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) control but it doesn't support selecting multiple dates at once.

Comment: not supported - you need to implement a custom skin that does (no idea how easy or difficult that might be)

Comment: Have you tried [`jfxtras`](http://jfxtras.org/) [`CalendarPicker`](http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-controls/jfxtras/scene/control/CalendarPicker.html)?

Comment: @kleopatra I am moving the answer to the comments, but I think this is more of a problem of a question not being within the scope of the site

Comment: @Sedrick agreed :)